# Angular - Why command NPM start --open 4300 does not work?

Tags: angular

I am trying to launch Chrome by firing NPM start --port 4300. But the same never works. I have checked package.json file too and I could not find any entry like http:\localhost:4200.

What is the mystery here?

Following are entries from package.json file:-

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "ngh": "ngh",
    "rimraf": "rimraf",
    "ngc": "node_modules/.bin/ngc",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "start:aot": "ng serve --aot",
    "build": "npm run clean:dist && ng build",
    "build:prod": "npm run build -- --prod",
    "build:prod:aot": "npm run build -- --prod --aot",
    "build:ci": "npm run build:prod && npm run build:prod:aot && npm run build:release",
    "build:release": "gulp build:release",
    "test": "ng test -sr",
    "test:coverage": "npm run clean:coverage && ng test -sr -cc",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "lint:styles": "stylelint ./src/framework/**/*.scss",
    "lint:ci": "npm run lint && npm run lint:styles",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "clean:dist": "npm run rimraf -- dist"
```

Is there some entry, which is stopping to open the application over port other than 4200?

best regards,
Sidd

Answer (score 1):

Add '-o' as an argument to your start script.

```
"start": "ng serve -o",
```

It will not only serve the application but open it in your default browser as you can see in the [serve docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/serve).

Additionally, if you want to specify a certain port where the application should run, use the '-port' argument as well:

```
"start": "ng serve -o --port 4200",
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't realised it was already answered, I think it wasn't by the time I started posting it. My bad

Answer (score 0):

You should use `--port` option to serve application on another port. For more information you can type `ng serve --help`.

So in package.json you can change your `start` script to this.

`"start": "ng serve --port 4300 --open"`